# p:commandButton don't fire the actionlistener method

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

My p:commandButton don't fire the action or actionListener (I tried both of them) and I don't know what is causing this problem.

I've been searching this site 2 days ago until now testing solutions of yours but none works for me.

I'm using JSF 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

here my code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
template="../template/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">
        <div id="button_bar">
            <div class="button_bar_left">
                <h:form id="frm_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{import.handleFile}"
                        id="fup"
                        mode="advanced" 
                        update=":form_table:table, :frm_btns:btn_remove, :frm_btns:btn_save, fup"
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx)$/"  />
                </h:form>
            </div>
            <div class="button_bar_right">
                <h:form id="frm_btns" >
                    <p:commandButton id="btn_save"
                        disabled="#{empty import.items}"
                        actionListener="#{import.save}"
                        update=":form_table:table,btn_save,btn_remove" 
                        value="#{msg['import.save']}"
                        ajax="false"
                        process="@all" 
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" />

                    <p:commandButton id="btn_remove" 
                        action="#{import.remove}" 
                        disabled="#{empty import.items}"
                        value="#{msg['import.remove']}"
                        update=":form_table:table,btn_save,btn_remove"
                        icon="ui-icon-trash" />

                    <p:commandButton id="btn_return" 
                        action="tecnical_team" 
                        value="#{msg['import.return']}"
                        icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-w"
                        ajax="false" />

                    <p:blockUI block=":form_table:table" trigger="#{p:component('btn_save')}">
                        <p:graphicImage value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                    </p:blockUI>
                </h:form>           
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="clear" />

        <div class="legend align_right">
            <div class="little_square_legend align_left" />
            <div class="text_legend"><h:outputText value="#{msg['import.legend']}"/></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear" /><br/>

        <h:panelGroup id="pg_table" styleClass="scrollable" layout="block">
            <h:form id="form_table">
                <p:dataTable id="table" var="item" value="#{import.items}" paginator="true" 
                    paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="20" rowStyleClass="#{item.problem ? 'problem_line' : null}">
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{import.allSelected}">
                                <p:ajax update="table" listener="#{import.selectAll}" />
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['import.table.item']}" sortBy="#{item.itemId}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.nrItem}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['import.table.sc.number']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.nrSc}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['import.table.item.group']}"> 
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.contract.nmContract}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['import.table.applicant']}"> 
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.applicant}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
```

and here is my managed Bean:

```
package com.xxx.web.mb;

import static com.xxx.enumeration.AuthorityType.PROJECT_MANAGER;
import static com.xxx.excel.ExcelToEntity.items;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;


@ManagedBean(name = "import")
@ViewScoped
public class ImportView implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 491969435579306400L;

    private List<Item> items;
    private Boolean allSelected;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{i18n}") private I18n i18n;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{unicaSession}") private Session session;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{importService}") private ImportService service;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{emailService}") private EmailService emailService;


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String save() {
        try {
            int saved = 0;
            System.out.println("Hello !");
            List<Item> selected = new ArrayList<Item>();
            if (items != null) {
                for (Item item : items) {
                    if (item.getSelected() && !item.getProblem()) {
                        item.setProject(session.getProject());
                        item.setDtRegistration(new Date());
                        selected.add(item);
                        saved ++;
                    } else if (item.getSelected() && item.getProblem()) {
                        Faces.errorMessage("A row with a problem is seleted");
                        return null;
                        //return;
                    }
                }

                if (saved == 0) {
                    Faces.infoMessage("Select at least one item");
                    return null;
                    //return;
                }

                service.save(selected);
                items.clear();

                emailService.send(i18n.getMessage("mail.message.new.items", saved), PROJECT_MANAGER);

                Faces.infoMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.saved.items", saved));
            }
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            Faces.errorMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.error.save.items"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String remove() {
        boolean removed = false;
        if (items != null) {
            Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Item item = (Item) iterator.next();
                if (item.getSelected()) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    removed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (removed) {
            Faces.infoMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.success.remove.items"));
        } else {
            Faces.alertMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.error.none.selected"));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void handleFile(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            if (items != null && !items.isEmpty()) {
                items.clear();
            }

            UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
            InputStream excel = file.getInputstream();
            ExcelMapping excelMapping = new ExcelMapping(excel);
            excelMapping.mapping();

            items = items(excelMapping.getExcelData());

            validate(items);

            if (FilterProblem.instance().notEmpty()) {
                Faces.errorMessage(FilterProblem.instance().get());
            }


        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            if (Assert.isNotNullOrEmpty(items)) { items.clear(); }
            Faces.errorMessage(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (Assert.isNotNullOrEmpty(items)) { items.clear(); }
            Faces.errorMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.error.handle.file"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (Assert.isNotNullOrEmpty(items)) { items.clear(); }
            Faces.errorMessage(i18n.getMessage("import.mb.error.obligatory.template"));
        } finally {
            FilterProblem.instance().clear();
        }
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (allSelected) {
                item.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                item.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void validate(List<Item> items) {
        FilterChain<Item> chain = new FilterChain<Item>();

        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            chain.add(new SCNumberFilter(items.get(0), service));
        }

        for (Item item : items) {
            chain.add(new RequiredFilter(item));
            chain.add(new DomainValidationFilter(item, service));
            chain.add(new ViewValidationFilter(item, service));
        }

        chain.execute();
    }


    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Boolean getAllSelected() {
        return allSelected;
    }

    public void setAllSelected(Boolean allSelected) {
        this.allSelected = allSelected;
    }

    public void setService(ImportService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void setI18n(I18n i18n) {
        this.i18n = i18n;
    }

    public void setEmailService(EmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }
}
```

It's freak me out ! Please help me !

Thanks !

PS: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Your `#{import.items}` seems to only ever get initialized in the `handleFile()` method. The the only two `<p:commandButtons/>` that call methods in your backing bean are `btn_remove` and `btn_add`. They are both marked `disabled="#{empty import.items}"`, which means that the buttons are initially rendered disabled. Also note that both reside inside `<h:form id="frm_btns"/>`.

**Here's the problem** - seemingly, the only place that tries (and fails) to update buttons (i.e render them functional) is your file upload component, but the update attribute says `update=":form_table:table, :form_table:btn_remove, :form_table:btn_save, fup"` when it should be `update=":form_table:table, :frm_btns:btn_remove, :frm_btns:btn_save, fup"`.

Next time, please check your ids before posting and definitely read up on http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Sorry rdcmg for the error on the update value and thanks for the advise

Comment: @rdcmg, I update the error in my code as you say. When I upload the file it updates 'items'property and the<p:commandbuttons /> goes enable, but when I submit the button save, the action don't be called.

Comment: Try adding using some client side developer tools such as chrome dev tools or firebug to see if the request is being sent and whether there is a response. Also, try setting your project stage to development in order to get some feedback.

Comment: My project stage is set to development already. I used firebug and it seems that the post has been made when I click on the button save. Any ideas on what could be causing the problem ? thanks @rdcmg

Comment: What does the response say? That should usually be enough let you know what's wrong. If the request is made and there is nothing wrong in the response, then how are you determining your listener isn't called?

Comment: I'm saying this, because in debug mode the breakpoint hasn't been reached. And put some     out.println in the listener method and nothing is write in log files.

Comment: Ok then, what does the AJAX response look like since you're saying the request is made?